# Is FIle.Exists() suitable for big directories?

Tags: c#

I asked this question earlier but it was closed because it wasn't "focused". So I have deleted that question to provide what I hope is a more focused question:

I have a task where I need to look for an image file over a network. The folder this file is in is over a network and this folder can have 1 mil to 2 mil images. Some of these images are 10 megabytes big. I have no control over this folder so I can't structure it. I am just providing the application to the customer to look for image files in this big folder.

I was going to use the C# File.Exist() method to look up the file.

Is the performance of File.Exists affected by the number of files in the directory and/or the size of those files?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it wouldn't be? Why anticipate problems that you don't yet have solutions to? Do you currently have any code at all that attempts to solve the problem which is demonstrably defective?

Comment: @madreflection what sort of details should I add? I'm genuinely confused as to what more you guys want me to do

Comment: Suppose the answer is "yes - File.Exists is slower the more files in the folder". What do you do then? What other ways do you know of to check if a file exists? Is it so slow that it's actually a _problem_? Your real question (if indeed the performance is a problem) is "is there a faster way than file.Exists for directories with lots of folders"?  If there's not, and you have no control of the structure, then what do you do?

Comment: @DStanley yes that was my question originally, but it was closed due to "focus" so i tried to simplify it to one question. I did ask if there is a a faster way than File.Exists? That being said, thanks for the feedback. Do you know of another way other than File.Exists for bigger directories?

Comment: @Datboydozy Without knowing a lot of the specifics of your application, one way to do it would be to maintain a separate index of these files. You could use a database to do this (e.g. SQLite), a flat file, really anything - but then you'd query against this index instead of the filesystem itself. Whether that's "better or worse" is probably dependent on your specific goals, but it's at least another option.

Answer (score 4):

The performance of File.Exists() mostly depends on the underlying file system (of the machine at the other end) and of course the network. Any reasonable file system will implement it in such a way that size won't matter.

However the total number of files may affect the performance, because of indexation of large number of entries. But again, a self respecting file system will use some kind of log (or even constant) lookup, so it should be negligible (even for 5mil files and log scale, the FS has to scan at most 23 entries, its nothing). The network will definitely be a bottleneck here.

That being said, YMMV and I encourage you to simply measure it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the size of the images will not be a factor, but the number of them will be. Those folders are unreasonably large and are going to be slow for many different I/O operations, including just listing them.

That aside, this is such a simple operation to test you really should just benchmark it yourself. Creating a simple console application that can connect to the network folder and check for known existing files, and known missing files will give you an idea of the time per operation you're looking at. It's not like you have to do a ton of implementation in order to test a single standard library function.